# AWS api gateway JSON-like body

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, mapping, aws-api-gateway, plaintext

I set up a POST ressource in API Gateway which invokes a Lamdba function, fine.
In the "integration request", for text/plain Content-type, I defined the following mapping :

```
#set($messageStr = $util.urlEncode($input.body))

    {
    "message" : "$messageStr"
    }
```

Problem is : whenever I POST data with JSON reserved characters, the integration request mapping thows

```
{"message": "Could not process payload"}
```

Example : `blablabla` will be correctly passed through to lambda, not `{blablabla` nor `a:e` ...

This seems like that method urlEncode expects JSON data.

Any idea how to pass whatever body as pure text ?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, it sounds like a bug on API Gateway. It tries to parse the body that starts '{'. I will create a follow-up item to fix it.

Comment: Cool thanks. I also posted this on AWS forum.

Comment: Hello. How can i stay informed about the fixing of this issue as it is blocking to me. Thanks